# Single arrow with heads on both sides pointing in same direction

Tags: tikz-pgf, arrows, tikz-arrows

Please consider the following example of an arrow I would like to draw in a `tikzpicture`-environment:

[image: arrow]

My **MWE** draws a `single arrow` but only with one head. Does anyone know how I can add a second head as shown in the picture above (i.e. an inverted triangle)?

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes,arrows}

\begin{document}


\tikzstyle{MyArrow} = [
    single arrow,
    draw=none,
    single arrow head extend=0ex,
    text centered,
    fill=black,
    node distance=4cm
    ]



\begin{figure}

    \centering
    \begin{tikzpicture}

    \node[MyArrow,name=a1] {\textcolor{white}{Beschaffung}};
    \node[MyArrow,name=a2,right of=a1]  {\textcolor{white}{Produktion}};

    \end{tikzpicture}

\end{figure}


\end{document}
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

As said in the comment, this is the new type of diagram of the [`smartdiagram`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/smartdiagram) package, available from version 0.2.

In order to obtain the same result displayed below, some customization is needed because by default each item in the sequence has different color.

The code (much more compact with respect to the manual definition):

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=2pt,png]{standalone}
\usepackage{smartdiagram}

\begin{document}
\smartdiagramset{uniform sequence color=true,
  sequence item uniform color=gray!50!black,
  sequence item border color=gray!50!white,
  sequence item text color=gray!50!white,
  sequence item border size=\pgflinewidth,
}
\smartdiagram[sequence diagram]{Beschauffung,Produktion}
\end{document}
```

---

*First version*

I won't use the `single arrow` shape for this, but rather the `signal` one from the library `shapes.symbols`.

You can customized it with `signal from=west` and `signal to=east` to achieve the desired heads.

An example:

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=2pt,png]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.symbols}

\tikzset{product size/.style={minimum width=2cm, 
    minimum height=1cm,
  },
  product/.style={
    draw,signal, 
    signal to=east, 
    signal from=west,
    product size,
    fill=gray!50!black,
    draw=gray!50!white,
    text=gray!50!white,
  },
}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\node[product] (first) {Beschauffung};
\node[product, anchor=west] at (first.east){Produktion};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

The result:

[image]

Here is a method to do things in a simpler manner and automatically:

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=2pt,png]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.symbols}

\tikzset{product size/.style={minimum width=2cm, 
    minimum height=1cm,
    text height=1ex,
  },
  product/.style={
    draw,signal, 
    signal to=east, 
    signal from=west,
    product size,
    fill=gray!50!black,
    draw=gray!50!white,
    text=gray!50!white,
  },
}

\newcommand{\diagram}[1]{%
 \foreach \x[count=\xi, count=\prevx from 0] in {#1}{%
  \ifnum\xi=1
    \node[product] (x-\xi) {\x};
  \else
    \node[product,anchor=west] (x-\xi) at (x-\prevx.east) {\x};
  \fi
 }
}


\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\diagram{One,Two,Three}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

The result:

[image]

Comment: This probably will be the next diagram type of [`smartdiagram`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/smartdiagram).