# text in different arrows

Tags: tikz-pgf, nodes, arrows

maybe someone can help me to get text in arrows and textboxes below

I have just get the arrows like this...

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[thick,black](0cm,0) -- ++(0:3cm) -- ++(45:1cm)  -- ++(135:1cm)-- ++(180:3cm)-- ++(270:1.4cm);
\draw[thick,black] (4cm,0) -- ++(0:3cm) -- ++(45:1cm)  -- ++(135:1cm)-- ++(180:3cm)-- ++(315:1cm)-- ++(225:1cm);
\draw[thick,black] (8cm,0) -- ++(0:3cm) -- ++(45:1cm)  -- ++(135:1cm)-- ++(180:3cm)-- ++(315:1cm)-- ++(225:1cm);
\end{tikzpicture}
```

i want to get text in that arrows (maybe there is a shape for node?) and text as a bulleted list below the arrows.

[image]

Comment: Hi Marcel and welcome to the site. Would you be able to provide a picture showing what you want for your result? A simple MS Paint picture would be fine, or even a handdrawn picture scanned in. That would make it easier to help you.

Comment: i cant load up a picture couse i havent enough reputation.

Comment: If you upload it to imgur, and tell me the url, I'll put it into your post for you.

Comment: http://imgur.com/FMNmXAC

Thanks :)

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436)

Comment: For the arrows you might find some clues in [Single arrow with heads on both sides pointing in same direction](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/100560/13304).

Comment: Yes, this looks like a job for Claudio's **[`smartdiagram` package](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/smartdiagram)**.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One possibility using the `signal` shape from the `shapes` library and two chains; the `enumitem` package was used to define a custom list with the modified labels:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{pifont}
\usetikzlibrary{chains,shapes,shadows}

\newcommand\mycircle{%
  \tikz\draw (0,0) circle (2pt);}
\newlist{myitemize}{itemize}{2}
\setlist[myitemize]{leftmargin=*,nolistsep}
\setlist[myitemize,1]{label=\ding{227}}
\setlist[myitemize,2]{label=\mycircle}

\tikzset{
initial/.style={
  draw=blue!50!cyan!40,
  shape=signal,
  text width=3cm,
  text depth=1cm,
  top color=blue!50!cyan!10,
  bottom color=blue!50!cyan!40,
  drop shadow
  },
other/.style={
  initial,
  signal from=west,
  text width=2.26cm
},
rect/.style={
  draw=blue!50!cyan!40,
  rectangle,
  text width=3cm,
  text depth=7cm,
  text height=5pt,
  top color=blue!50!cyan!10,
  bottom color=blue!50!cyan!40,
  drop shadow
  }
}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{scope}[start chain,node distance=5mm, every node/.style={on chain}]
\node[initial] {text 1};
\node[other] {text 2};
\node[other] {text 3};
\end{scope}
\begin{scope}[yshift=-4.8cm,start chain,node distance=5mm, every node/.style={on chain}]
\node[rect] {%
  \begin{myitemize}
  \item First.
  \item Second.
    \begin{myitemize}
    \item First.
    \item Second.
  \end{myitemize}
  \end{myitemize}%
};
\node[rect] {%
  \begin{myitemize}
  \item First.
  \item Second.
  \end{myitemize}%
};
\node[rect] {%
  \begin{myitemize}
  \item First.
  \item Second.
  \item Third.
  \end{myitemize}%
};
\end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]