# How to draw a rectangle shaped arrow-jigsaw with bullets below

Tags: tikz-pgf, draw

Like this, with multicolor shades of blue
[image: Multicolor jigsaw arrow rectangles shades of blue]

Thanks!

Comment: Could you show us what you have tried so-far in terms of a MWE?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I introduce the `\blivet{<color>}{<arrow label>}{<sub items>}` macro.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz,stackengine,listofitems} 
\setstackEOL{\\}
\makeatletter\let\gaddtomacro\g@addto@macro\makeatother
\newcommand\blivet[3]{%
  \setsepchar{\\}%
  \readlist*\myitems{#3}%
  \foreachitem\x\in\myitems{%
    \ifnum\xcnt=1\def\tmp{}\else\gaddtomacro\tmp{\\}\fi%
    \gaddtomacro\tmp{$\bullet$~}%
    \expandafter\gaddtomacro\expandafter\tmp\expandafter{\x}}%
  \sffamily\stackengine{12pt}{%
    \begin{tikzpicture}
      \draw [fill=#1] (-2,0) -- (-1.5,.6) -- (-2,1.2) -- (1.5,1.2) -- (2,.6)
       -- (1.5,0) -- (-2,0) node [midway,right=1ex, above=1.2ex] {\large\textbf{\strut#2}};
    \end{tikzpicture}%
  }{%
    \renewcommand\stackalignment{l}%
    \expandafter\Longstack\expandafter{\tmp}%
  }{U}{c}{F}{F}{S}%
}
\begin{document}
\blivet{green!35!blue!20}{Learn}{Seminars\\ Research Papers\\ Training}
\blivet{green!35!blue!40}{Strategize}{Design Thinking\\Business Strategy\\Product Roadmap}
\blivet{green!35!blue!60}{Build}{Discovery\\ Delivery\\Transfer}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 7):

There are some packages for this stuff, but I prefer this

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\def\arrownode (#1,#2) node[#3] #4{%
\begin{scope}[scale=0.75]
    \coordinate (x) at (#1,#2);
    \path[draw,fill=#3] ($(x)+(-2,0)$)--($(x)+(-3,1)$)--($(x)+(1,1)$)--($(x)+(2,0)$)--($(x)+(1,-1)$)--($(x)+(-3,-1)$)--cycle;
    \draw ($(x)+(-.25,0)$) node {\bfseries\sffamily#4};
\end{scope}
}
\arrownode (-5,0) node[blue!10] {Learn};
\foreach \i/\txt in {1.5/Seminars,2/Research papers,2.5/Training} {
    \draw[fill=black] (-5.25,-\i) circle (1pt) node [right=1.5ex] {\small\sffamily\txt};
}
\arrownode (0,0) node[blue!30] {Strategize};
\foreach \i/\txt in {1.5/Design Thinking,2/Business Strategy,2.5/Product Roadmap} {
    \draw[fill=black] (-1.5,-\i) circle (1pt) node [right=1.5ex] {\small\sffamily\txt};
}
\arrownode (5,0) node[blue!50] {Build};
\foreach \i/\txt in {1.5/Discovery,2/Delivery,2.5/Transfer} {
    \draw[fill=black] (2.25,-\i) circle (1pt) node [right=1.5ex] {\small\sffamily\txt};
}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 6):

Something to start with:

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes,arrows, positioning}

\begin{document}
    %https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/175679/text-inside-custom-tikz-draw
    \tikzset{product size/.style={minimum width=4cm, 
            minimum height=2cm,
        },
        product/.style={
            draw,signal, 
            signal to=east, 
            signal from=west,
            product size,
            fill=gray!50!black,
            draw=gray!50!white,
            text=white,font=\bfseries,
        },
    }


    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \node[product,fill=blue!50, draw=white] (first) {Learn};
    \node[product, fill=blue!75, draw = white, anchor=west]  [right=1cm of first.east] (second) {Strategize};
    \node[product, fill=blue, draw = white, anchor=west][right=1cm of second.east](third){Build};
    % list
    \node [below=7.5mm of first,anchor=center,  align=left, text width=4cm ] (versopt) {
        \begin{itemize}           
    \item lkjh
\item kjh
\item ghl
        \end{itemize}
    };
    \node [below=7.5mm of second,anchor=center,  align=left, text width=4cm ] (versopt) {
    \begin{itemize}           
    \item jkh
    \item hkj
    \item lkh
    \end{itemize}
};
    \node [below=7.5mm of third,anchor=center,  align=left, text width=4cm ] (versopt) {
    \begin{itemize}           
    \item lkjh
\item  lkjh
\item lkjh
    \end{itemize}
};
    \end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

which will give you:

[image]

Now, starting from color selection (you can use use `gpick`), I hope you can do much more customisation as you want. I leave that you.