# Arrow mark with text by using tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf, arrowwithtext

My code follows:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{tikz}%
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.arrows}%
\begin{document}

\def\splarrow#1{%
\begin{tikzpicture}%
[every node/.style={single arrow,draw=none}]\node[fill=cyan]{#1};%
\end{tikzpicture}}%

\splarrow{Arrow 1}

\end{document}
```

I got the output as:

[image]

But actually I need as:

[image]

Please suggest how to fix it...

Comment: See https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/100560/single-arrow-with-heads-on-both-sides-pointing-in-same-direction/100562#100562

Comment: Many Thanks for this, note that my case color varies for each arrows, please suggest

Comment: That is what `smartdiagram` does by default, part of the code in Claudio's answer is for making the colour uniform.

Comment: Sorry for disturbing, smartdiagram does all the arrow's tails and heads are same, but my case first arrow tail should be straight and the following arrow's tails are different and same for others ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the non-`smartdiagram` code by Claudio Fiandrino in [Single arrow with heads on both sides pointing in same direction](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/100560/single-arrow-with-heads-on-both-sides-pointing-in-same-direction/100562#100562), with just a few small modifications. I've placed comments in the code where I've made changes.

[image: output of code]

```
% Original code by Claudio Fiandrino in
% https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/100560/single-arrow-with-heads-on-both-sides-pointing-in-same-direction/100562#100562
\documentclass[tikz,border=2pt,png]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.symbols}

\tikzset{product size/.style={minimum width=2cm, 
    minimum height=1cm,
    text height=1ex,
  },
  product/.style={ % removed fill and text colour setting
    draw,signal, 
    signal to=east, 
    signal from=west,
    product size,
    draw=black!50
  },
}

\newcommand{\diagram}[1]{%
 % changed from "\x in" to "\x/\clr in"
 \foreach [count=\xi, count=\prevx from 0] \x/\clr in {#1}{%
  \ifnum\xi=1
    % added fill=\clr,signal from=none
    \node[product,fill=\clr,signal from=none] (x-\xi) {\x};
  \else
    % added fill=\clr
    \node[product,fill=\clr,anchor=west] (x-\xi) at (x-\prevx.east) {\x};
  \fi
 }
}


\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
% "text/colour name", instead of just "text"
\diagram{One/blue!50,Two/red!50,Three/green!50}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Or if you want shades of the same colour, you can try something like this:

[image: output of code]

```
% Original code by Claudio Fiandrino in
% https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/100560/single-arrow-with-heads-on-both-sides-pointing-in-same-direction/100562#100562
\documentclass[tikz,border=2pt,png]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.symbols}

\tikzset{product size/.style={minimum width=2cm, 
    minimum height=1cm,
    text height=1ex,
  },
  product/.style={ % removed fill and text colour setting
    draw,signal, 
    signal to=east, 
    signal from=west,
    product size,
    draw=black!50
  },
}

\newcommand{\diagram}[1]{%
 % add "evaluate={\clrpercent=10*\xi;}"
 \foreach [count=\xi, count=\prevx from 0,evaluate={\clrpercent=10*\xi;}] \x in {#1}{%
  \ifnum\xi=1
    % added fill=blue!\clrpercent!white,signal from=none
    \node[product,fill=blue!\clrpercent!white,signal from=none] (x-\xi) {\x};
  \else
    % added fill=blue!\clrpercent!white
    \node[product,fill=blue!\clrpercent!white,anchor=west] (x-\xi) at (x-\prevx.east) {\x};
  \fi
 }
}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\diagram{One,Two,Three}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```